# node + requirejs: module is not defined

Tags: node.js, module, requirejs

Getting a `module is not defined` error attempting to import a module from the local project.  Using node and requirejs -

```
Error: Evaluating /Users/Projects/stash/NODE/project_js/src/foo.js as module "foo" failed with error: ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

Code looks like -

```
(function() {

const requirejs = require('requirejs')

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: __dirname,
    nodeRequire:require
});

//var foo = requirejs('foo.js');

requirejs(['foo'], function() {
foo().then(data => {
    data.foreach(function(item, index, data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(item))
      })
    });
  })

})();
```

The module has the following export -

```
module.exports = function foo() {
.
.
.
return results
}
```

I've tried loading the module synchronously as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this part](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#2) of their doc: if the module to be loaded (`foo` here) is found by RequireJS (i.e. its configuration allows it to find the module), then this module has to be declared using `define` instead of Node's `exports`.

I just tried this, which works:

> directory structure

```
test/
  index.js
  foo.js
```

> `index.js`

```
(function() {

  const requirejs = require('requirejs');

  requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: __dirname,
    nodeRequire:require
  });

  requirejs(['foo'], (foo) => {
    console.log('loaded!', foo, foo());
  });
})();
```

> `foo.js` (that's the interesting part)

```
define(function() {
  return function foo() {
    return 'fooResult';
  }
});
```

Using `module.exports = ...` gave me the error you have.

However this RequireJS API is not "loadable" by Node's built-in `require`, hence the need for a precise configuration that reflects a clear separation between Node-required modules ([CommonJS API](https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#commonjs)) and RequireJS-defined modules ([AMD API](https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd)). (Actually you can check the whole ["Why AMD?"](https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) page, that should help a lot for your work with RequireJS.)